# How to build one deployable Java app from OSGI Maven bundles?

Tags: java, maven, osgi, apache-karaf, maven-bundle-plugin

I have a parent Maven OSGI project and several children projects, with one child project being the Launcher. The parent pom.xml has pom while children pom.xml(s) bundle and I use Maven Bundle Plugin. With Mvn clean install, MANIFEST.MF and jar files are successfully created for the children projects.

However I do not know the next step. How can I create a single java app for the parent project + bundles which is executable? I have looked into Karaf (other options?) but do not know how to create a single jar for the parent project.

Thank you

Comment: you need an osgi container to *run* osgi bundles (think of how you need a servlet container  to have a servlet) - check out apache felix. if you are building a web app, go for apache sling - which is built on felix and also provides a java content repository.

Comment: @awd Thank you for the suggestion. I am building a desktop application.